# Get the full element instead of just the text or a specific attribute with cheeriogs

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, cheerio

[image]

I would like to print this complete element:

```
<span class="flag_16 left_16 argentina_16_left">Argentina - Liga Profesional Argentina</span>
```

But when I try to retrieve `Regiao` without adding `Region.text()` or `Region.attr()`, the script runs endlessly. Is there any way to receive the entire element and not just the `text` or a specific `attribute`?

```
function test() {
    var url = 'https://int.soccerway.com/';

    const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

  var Regiao = $('#date_matches-87 > th:nth-child(1) > h3');
    Logger.log(Regiao);
}
```

`CheerioGS` documentation:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

Google App Script Library ID for `CheerioGS`:

`1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`

Comment: If you can get the text and if you know the class name, wouldn't it have been easier just to add the tags to the text? `<span class="flag_16 left_16 argentina_16_left">` + `text` + `</span>`

Comment: Hi @YuriKhristich So actually I'd like to find a way to retrieve the entire element to find out what attributes are within it, in the case of taking dynamic pages for example, then figure out what's within that path.